# Knockout - select first item on combobox programatically

Tags: knockout.js, dropdown

I have a Knockout bound Combobox.

```
<input title="Country" class="CountryID ComboBox" id="CountryID_GUIDGUIDGUID" type="text" data-bind="SCombo: { Value: CountryID, ValueMember: 'CountryID', Display: 'Country', Caption: 'Country*', Source: MyCountryList}">
```

I cannot find out how to programmatically set the value (from the console).

Normal jquery  `$("#target").val($("#target option:first").val());`
does not work.

Someone suggested

```
ko.dataFor("CountryID_GUIDGUIDGUID").DropDownProperty("Albania");
```

but I cannot get that to work  - `Unable to get property 'DropDownProperty' of undefined or null reference`

Comment: Woa there. That's no combobox, it's `type="text"`. There's a custom binding handler on it that suggests some kind of plugin, but all info around that (incl the binding handler's code) is missing in your question. Please make sure your question contains a [mcve].

Comment: You should use your actual property name instead of "DropDownProperty". So in your case `CountryID` e.eg `ko.dataFor("CountryID_GUIDGUIDGUID").CountryID("Albania");` however because you have  `CountryID` as the valuemamber you need to use the ID of Albania instead of the country name

Comment: Also, in general, with Knockout you should *never* change the DOM if you can help it. Change the view model instead, let KO handle DOM updates.

Comment: Apologies, first time on Knockout ever and Im not good with front end. Nemesv, i tried the code thanks but now get the error "CountryID" undefined or null. This is only for testing purposes that I need this to save time

Comment: If you're quite new I suggest running through [the tutorials](http://learn.knockoutjs.com/) before asking questions. They're very good, easy to complete, and answer a lot of questions you may otherwise want to ask. - In any case, beginner and senior alike will need to provide a minimal repro to allow others to help efficiently.

Comment: i learned from it, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Knockout, you should think in terms of setting values in your model, rather than manipulating DOM elements. Assuming that the `Value` property for the custom binding works like the standard `value` binding, you just need to set CountryID to the desired value. It will be something like

```
vm.CountryID(vm.MyCountryList()[0]);
```

depending on your context and whether `MyCountryList` is an observableArray and what its structure is.